# How to prevent ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in my code which relies on Router Event Observable

Tags: angular

I have read many article on the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError and I understand why it is happening and how to work around it in a hacky way.
But I am at loss how to fix my issue in a good way and I was hoping anyone here has a suggestion.

My code is simple:
Render a list of categories based on the Router path. So when path is `/music/foo` a Router resolver get's all child categories of Foo and renders that in a list.
When you then click on a child, let's say `bar` the path becomes `/music/foo/bar` and the Router resolver get's all children of `bar`.

This all works fine.
However, I am adding a bread crumb component which has an input called `path`. This path value is undefined to start with.
Then in the Router Events subscription, it gets assigned a value.
Code looks like this:

```
export class CategoriesComponent {
  @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<Category>;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Category>([]);

  // get media based on finished route event. The data should be there because resolver is blocking
  media$ = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      startWith(this.router),
      map(() => this.appState.get<CategoryCollection>('categoryCollection')),
      tap(categories => {
        const { path, type } = extractMediaPath(this.router.url);


        // to prevent expressionhaschanged error until I have a better solution
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.path = `${type}${path}`.replace(/\/$/, '');

         });
        console.log(path);
        const items = this.sort(categories[type], path);
        if (items.length && items[0].media) {
          this.allowAddCategory = false;
          this.displayedColumns = type === CategoryType.MUSIC ? [...MEDIA_MUSIC_COLUMNS] : [...MEDIA_VIDEO_COLUMNS];
        } else {
          this.allowAddCategory = true;
          this.displayedColumns = [...CATEGORY_COLUMNS];
        }
        this.dataSource.data = items;
      })
    );
```

The `setTimeout` hack prevents the error but I am not satisfied with this. And another error happens because of `this.allowAddCategory = true / false` at the bottom of the subscription block. I can't keep wrapping code in setTimeouts.

I am trying to understand how to rewrite the code and why the error happens.
`media$` is subscribed to in the template using an `*ngIf` plus `async` pipe.

Apparently the DOM get's rendered before the Router Events subscription has finished and that possible triggers the ExpressionChanged error.

But I can only decide the true value of `path` and `allowAddCategory` in the body of the event subscription.
Before that I don't have enough information to calculate the value.

What is the best solution to a scenario sketched by me?

Comment: One solution I tried is moving away from the template subscription and subscript to the Router Events from the ngOnInit function. This solved the expression error so that is one way to do it. But now I have to unsubscribe manually from the Subscription using takeUntil . I subscribed via template so I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the `rxjs` part after `ngAfterViewInit` so that the changes happen after the view is rendered, this will solve your issue!

```
export class CategoriesComponent {
  @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<Category>;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Category>([]);

  // get media based on finished route event. The data should be there because resolver is blocking
  media$ = of(false)

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      startWith(this.router),
      map(() => this.appState.get<CategoryCollection>('categoryCollection')),
      tap(categories => {
        const { path, type } = extractMediaPath(this.router.url);


        // to prevent expressionhaschanged error until I have a better solution
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.path = `${type}${path}`.replace(/\/$/, '');

         });
        console.log(path);
        const items = this.sort(categories[type], path);
        if (items.length && items[0].media) {
          this.allowAddCategory = false;
          this.displayedColumns = type === CategoryType.MUSIC ? [...MEDIA_MUSIC_COLUMNS] : [...MEDIA_VIDEO_COLUMNS];
        } else {
          this.allowAddCategory = true;
          this.displayedColumns = [...CATEGORY_COLUMNS];
        }
        this.dataSource.data = items;
      })
    );
  }
}
```